# Easy way to create depth

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects

I am creating a logo for which I need circles to create the illusion of depth. The attached image shows the sort of effect I am trying to replicate.

What would be the best way to do this in Photoshop (or Illustrator)?

[image: Logo illustration]

I have tried to **create the effect manually**. However, it would be time consuming to draw all the circles, apply transform to it and and still maintain the natural depth of the apple.

I am wondering if there are other ways to do this, and I would like to learn how the author probably created this depth.

Comment: I have tried to create the effect manually. However, it would be time consuming to draw all the circles, apply transform to it and and still maintain the natural depth of the apple. I am wondering if there are other ways to do this, and I would like to learn how the author probably created this depth.

Comment: just because you feel something is hard and time consuming does not men that was not what they did. I would say they did it manually, if not they used a custom tool. Theres about 35 ellipses even taking 2 minutes per ellipse its still just an hour of work. Anyway if you feel its hard then the author has succeeded keeping his job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for too quick a fix. Logo creation takes time. This effect can be achieved quite easily though. Draw a rectangle roughly the size of your final shape and fill it with overlapping circles up to the edge of the square. Make sure there are quite a few smaller circles near the edge to fake the perspective. Colour all the circles random colours. In the transparency panel change the opacity to about 90% and set the layer style to multiply. Select all these circles and click object...expand.  Now over the top of these shapes draw the final shape of your logo (in this case an apple). Select everything. Now all you have to do is in the menus go Object...Envelope Distort...Make with top object.

[image: Envelope Distort..Make with top object]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! I agree that logo creation should be a precise process and that it takes time. Your steps however give me the tools to start with

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but it looks like the effect was based on the ellipses mapped onto the surface of an Illustrator 3D Revolve effect. The result was probably expanded, edited and given a clipping mask.

Answer (score 1):

How much are you charging the client? Shouldn't you spend a bit of time considering they are paying you. I'd say the example was created manually - the ellipses are tilted and warped along fairly simple (not exact) contours - the larger spots are transparent and covering the smaller spots which indicate the back surface.

Answer (score 0):

Try Illustrators Bloat effect! Although, you will still need to draw the main aspects of the logo yourself ie the circles etc